# simplified query mysql union

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, union

this is my first question at stackoverflow, so please be kind

this is my table

| namadokter | namaoutlet | notransaksi | tanggalresep | totaltagihan |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| richard chandra sp | kfa | kfa132 | 2023-06-01 | 1200 |
| richard chandra sp | kfa | kfa132 | 2023-06-01 | 1300 |
| richard chandra spb | kfb | kfb133 | 2023-06-01 | 700 |
| richard chandra spb | kfb | kfb133 | 2023-06-01 | 800 |
| agus hidayat sp | kfa | kfa100 | 2023-06-01 | 1000 |
| agus hidayat sp | kfa | kfa100 | 2023-06-01 | 2000 |
| agus hidayat spb | kfb | kfb111 | 2023-06-01 | 3000 |
| agus hidayat spb | kfb | kfb111 | 2023-06-01 | 2000 |

this is my query

```
SELECT  *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY namadokter) row_num
  FROM (
(SELECT  namadokter,namaoutlet,  COUNT(notransaksi) AS jenis_obat,sum(totaltagihan)
FROM laporandokterunitsurabaya
where namadokter like '%richard chandra%' and (tanggalresep BETWEEN (SELECT tstart FROM tanggal WHERE id=1) AND (SELECT tend FROM tanggal WHERE id=1))
group by namaoutlet
order by namadokter) 
union 
(SELECT  namadokter,namaoutlet,  COUNT(notransaksi) AS jenis_obat,sum(totaltagihan)
FROM laporandokterunitsurabaya
where namadokter like '%agus hidayat%' and (tanggalresep BETWEEN (SELECT tstart FROM tanggal WHERE id=1) AND (SELECT tend FROM tanggal WHERE id=1))
group by namaoutlet
order by namadokter) 
)a

order by namadokter
```

this is the result

| row_num | namadokter | namaoutlet | jenis_obat | sum(totaltagihan) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | richard chandra sp | kfa | 2 | 2500 |
| 2 | richard chandra spb | kfb | 2 | 1500 |
| 3 | agus hidayat sp | kfa | 2 | 3000 |
| 4 | agus hidayat sp | kfb | 2 | 5000 |

my query is working, but it takes times when i got 30 or more select to union. i guess its because when i use 30 select wildcard it querying 30 times to.is there any posibility to use only one select.

Comment: Question about optimizing running code is better asked at [codereview.se]

Comment: Please add some sample data and the result you get

Comment: oke, noted, ill try at codereview, thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @jens i already add sample data and the result i get, thanks

Comment: @Community i already add additional details, thanks

Comment: Is your data so untidy that you have to include a wildcard before namadokter? Also please add table definitions as text so we can see what indexes you have. and add an explain.

Comment: @P.Salmon yes, the data is untidy. its excel file from local cashier pos system and i try to make it online

Comment: an index on namadoktor could be used if you don't need the preceding wildcard, if you do then it won't. Consider periodically cleansing the data to optimise. and you didn't publish the table definition and explain.

Comment: To help you with your [tag:query-optimization] question, we need to see your table definitions, your index definitions, and the output of EXPLAIN. Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info), then [edit] your question. Also, `LIKE '%text string%'` is a notoriously [non-sargable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable#Text_example) query performance antipattern. It's worth a *lot* of work to avoid it in a big system.